# Where and how to get `identityId` using AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

So I'm trying to follow along the guide in the docs and I'm stuck here

```
Storage.get('test.txt', { 
  level: 'protected', 
  identityId: 'xxxxxxx' // the identityId of that user
})
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

How does one get that `identityId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a hack to this from `Auth.currentUserCredentials()` by saving the `identityId` to a custom attribute on successful user login:

```
const CUSTOM_IDENTITY_FIELD = "custom:identityId";

if (attributes && !attributes[CUSTOM_IDENTITY_FIELD]) {
    await Auth.updateUserAttributes(currUser, {
      [CUSTOM_IDENTITY_FIELD]: (await Auth.currentUserCredentials())
        .identityId,
    });
    onInfo("Welcome to Tippify, " + currUser.username);
}
```

With this, I could also implement a `Firebase` first-time log in functionality.
Later when I wanted to query the user image from `Storage`:

```
Storage.get(user.picture, {
    level: "protected",
    identityId: user[CUSTOM_IDENTITY_FIELD],
})
  .then(setPicture)
  .catch(onError);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's still looking for the answer, this worked for me (in Amplify V6):

```
import { fetchAuthSession } from 'aws-amplify/auth'

...

const credentials = await fetchAuthSession()
console.log(credentials.identityId)
```